Relay for android Studio: Couldn't convert node icon: Unrecognized type NodeType.BooleanOperation
Good day
I'm trying to import ui component from Figma into my android project using Relay(Version 0.3.11) but I got the component without the icons and it shows the next warning in android studio:
(https://i.sstatic.net/2vNwr.png)
here is what I got:
(https://i.sstatic.net/XKo0j.png)
here is how I added the component in relay for Figma:
(https://i.sstatic.net/ToRUv.png)
I looked around and it seems nobody got a similar problem
